# Unusual Gem in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I bring the Unusual Gem to an appraiser?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38929/how-do-i-bring-the-unusual-gem-to-an-appraiser)

I bought a house in Solitude and when I was exploring it I found and unusual gem. I took it to the appraiser named Moul but he only tells me to get out of his way. How do I get him to look at the gem?

Answer (score 0):

your supposed to take it to vex, part of the thieves guild in Riften (within the ratway warrens, part of the main story).  then he tells you its part of a crown and you need all 24 so called "unusual gems" (name changes after he tells you this). find em all and rebuild it for big bucks when selling it. I MEAN BIG