# Where can I find all of the Unusual Gems?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are all the Stones of Barenziah located? (No Stone Unturned)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/where-are-all-the-stones-of-barenziah-located-no-stone-unturned)

Is there a big reward for collecting them? The ones I've found so far involved stealing from Jarls, so there had better be a hefty price on them.